# Approximation for fractional function

Tags: approximation, education

Let $x$ be a non-negative variable. Is there any good exponential approximation for the following fractional function,
\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{x}{ax+b}
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers. Is there any other kind of good approximations except exponential functions?

Comment: This function is not "exponential" at all and is relatively simple from a numerical/computational perspective (in that it only requires finitely-many additions, multiplications, and divisions to compute). If you give some context for your question it might be possible to provide a solution to you actual problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "approximation"?  If $|x|$ is very large, then $f(x)\sim \frac 1a$ (trusting that $a\neq 0$)  But this is a terrible approximation when $x\sim -\frac ba$.

Comment: You ask about $x$ "a non-negative variable", but otherwise do not indicate what domain of "approximation" is involved.  Note that $f(0) = 0$ and an exponential is never zero.  Also $f(x) \to 1/a$ as $x\to \infty$, but an exponential will tend to infinity or to zero as $x\to \infty$.   It's hard to see why you would try to fit an exponential to this simple rational function on the non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $\frac{x}{ax+b}=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{a(ax+b)}$ is a hyperbola. It has a vertical and horizontal asymptote whereas the function you want to approximate it by has only a horizontal asymptote. This is going to result in some part of the graph being a terrible approximation. So unless you can specify some range then the approximation will always be bad.

I would recommend trying for the same horizontal asymptote but beyond that it will never be a good fit.

Edit: Assuming you are interested in only $x\ge0$ part of the graph and $a$ and $b$ are both positive then there is a y-intercept of $0$. So a graph of $\frac{1}{a}(1-c^{-x})$  would give some similarity. Adjusting the value of $c$ would let you tweak the fit.